# How to change the href of link using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex, variables, hyperlink, replace

I would like to **change** the URL of the link.

Here's the code

```
<div id="content">
  ...
  <a href="/mbs/articleVC.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=822907&cpage=10">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleVC.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=822908&cpage=11">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=802894&cpage=&mbsW=search&select=stt&opt=1&keyword=keyword1">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=802895&cpage=&mbsW=search&select=stt&opt=1&keyword=keyword2">link</a>
  ...
</div>
```

Replace with:

```
<div id="content">
  ...
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=822907&cpage=10">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=822908&cpage=11">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=802894&cpage=&mbsW=search&select=stt&opt=1&keyword=keyword">link</a>
  <a href="/mbs/articleV.php?mbsC=freebbs&mbsIdx=802895&cpage=&mbsW=search&select=stt&opt=1&keyword=keyword2">link</a>
  ...
</div>
```

There are many links on the page.
How to replace from 'article**VC**.php' to 'article**V**.php' using jQuery?

Comment: I'm curious "why?" you're wanting to do this.  If you've permanently moved or renamed the pages, the HTML should be updated.  Otherwise, this should be done on the server using `mod_rewrite` or `redirect 301`.

Comment: @Sparky672 I think it is a good way. But I can't. Because this problem is to create a chrome extension.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a hint regarding the real purpose of such a browser extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***FIRST ONE IS BETTER AND FASTER***

```
$('#content a').attr('href', function(index, Oldhref) {
  return Oldhref.replace(/articleVC/ ,'articleV')
});
```

or

```
$('#content a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/articleVC/ ,'articleV'));
});
```

Comment: @user1382616 Welcome, best way to thanks is accepting as answer.

Comment: @thecodeparadox +1 the second one could be made as fast and efficient as the first one if you use `this.href = this.href.replace(...)`. However, if efficiency is a concern, the for loop would be the way to go anyway.

Comment: @KevinB hmm, but I compare my self and frequently we use second one. cordial thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('#content a[href*="articleVC.php"]').each(function() {
    href = $(this).attr('href').replace('articleVC.php' ,'articleV.php');
    $(this).attr('href', href);
});​​
```

[Test Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LAS9B/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a', '#content').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace('articleVC', 'articleV');
});​
```

If faster for some reason is better :-)

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i<elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].href = elms[i].href.replace('articleVC', 'articleV');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('#content a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('articleVC.php','articleV.php'));
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('articleVC.php', 'articleV.php'));
});
```

You can use the `each` function to iterate over all the matched `<a>` elements, for each of them take the 'href' attribute by calling `attr('href')`, use `replace` method of `String` to get a replaced string, then assign it again to the 'href' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using regular expressions.

Using jQuery: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VLAJD/))

```
$('#content a').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace(/articleVC\.php/, 'articleV.php');
});
```

In vanilla JavaScript: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BR69J/2/))

```
var links = document.getElementById('content').children;
for(l in links) {
    links[l].href = links[l].href.replace(/articleVC\.php/, 'articleV.php');
};
```